# How to play mp4 (actually GIFs converted to mp4)?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android App where I am using [Glide](https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos) to play animated GIF (.gif) files and it is working very well.

But when GIF files are heavy in size so I wanted to convert them to mp4 and use the same in my app. I have gif to mp4 conversion tools.

I couldn't find any library or solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need a VideoView control on your layout file. Use this code to activate it (assuming you have your mp4 file at `res/raw` folder):

```
VideoView vd = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your-package-name/"+R.raw.yourmp4filename);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
vd.setMediaController(mc);
vd.setVideoURI(uri);
vd.start();
vd.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this play like GIF?

Comment: This plays and also detects when video is ended. Do you think you can handle how to start playing again?

Answer (score 0):

Androids MediaPlayer has some problems playing some media formats. you can instead use [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer) for that purpose.

In the example below I am using Exoplayer to play an `.mp4` from `raw` folder like a gif in my app.

XML:

```
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        app:use_controller="false"
        app:hide_on_touch="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

Java:

```
private void playVideo(int resourceId) {
    SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getContext()).build();
    binding.videoView.setPlayer(player);
    Uri uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(resourceId);
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);
    player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
    player.prepare();
    player.play();
}
```

Please note that this implementation does not repeat the video file after completion. but surely there are ways to do that with ExoPlayer as well.